# How to convert non-Latin numerals to their Latin counterparts

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a system in a different language implemented in Unicode. The condition is that the system must also accept Unicode characters (for digits) and process them accordingly. Is it possible to convert any Unicode characters(that represents numbers) to a sensible English numbers equivalent?

How can I implement that in Javascript?

EDIT: I searched the web and found a chart in unicode.org . There are codes corresponding to the literals i want there. Now, how do i read the code from the input unicode string ?

Comment: "convert any Unicode characters to a sensible English equivalent" Doesn't make any sense. What do you mean?

Comment: not characters, but numbers, :)

Comment: You could decouple the presentation (in the native locale) from the storage (in your backend), and convert between the two the same way you would convert decimal to binary.

Comment: @normalocity : Sorry I could not understand :) . My question is simple: How do i convert ० (zero) to 0 ?

Comment: You could decouple the presentation (in the native locale) from the storage (in your backend), and convert between the two similarly to the way you would convert decimal to binary, or other conversions. Since you're dealing with numerical values rather than trying to transpose letters, this should be a conquerable subset of a larger character mapping problem. Can you provide particularly tricky examples you're running into?

Comment: @cipher is there always a one-to-one mapping between a given character in one locale and the equivalent Arabic numeral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) - which is what I presume you mean by "English" or "normal" digits?

Comment: I am going to edit this question to say what I think it is asking, but I'm not sure. Please edit it back if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @normalocity : yeah, the locale i am working on has one-to-one mapping between arabic numeral

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode

Comment: do you have information about what locale is used for numerals? this is not trivial, you need to approach each locale separately I suppose. For example, Latin numerals often use more than one character for each (Arabic) digit.

Comment: The conversion could not be codepoint-by-codepoint but must occur at the abstract level, e.g. Tamil single character for the number ten (10), which requires two numerals in the ASCII/Latin range, is ௰. See wikipedia article above.

Comment: @Tim : Can you suggest something after my edit? Fortunately, i am working on Devanagari which does not have such things. 0 corresponds to ०  and 9 corresponds to ९ . Nothing more. nothing less

Comment: @cipher: see mihi's good suggestion below.  In javascript you could create a hashed object with the key being the Unicode codepoint and the data being the ASCII-range [your "sensible English equivalent"] counterpart value. But approach this cautiously if these numbers are something other than addresses.

Comment: @Tim I am a beginner: I could not completely understand what you're trying to say. I have a series of input numbers in another locale to convert it into the arabic numeral. how can that me simply done ?

Comment: If a single locale, with a small and simple set of characters for numerals, then your switch statement is a good stop-gap solution. But to support multiple locales and the full set of characters that are numerals,  mihi's suggestion to cull the relevant data from the database and store it as JSON is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Unicode Database](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) contains in column 6-8 information about digit values, decimal digit values and number values (like `U+216E: ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE HUNDRED` has a number value of 500).

To use this in JavaScript, you might parse that file with some other language and dump the information you need as JSON or similar, and then just look up the value in the JSON from JavaScript.

[Documentation of the Unicode Database file format](http://old.kpfu.ru/eng/departments/ktk/test/perl/lib/unicode/UCDFF301.html#Field%20Formats)

Either you dump the unicode codepoints into your JSON like this `"\u20ac"` for `U+20AC`, then you can just compare the characters, or you can use `someString.charCodeAt(somePosition).toString(16)` to convert that character to a hex string (like `20ac`) to compare from there.

Comment: So, you mean something like this:

var somestring ="००११"; //unicode value
if(somestring.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) == "unicode_eqiv") {
    //do something!
}

?

Comment: Converting between Unicode codepoint and its string equivalent is not your end-goal, although it could be a means to your end. You want to convert the non-Latin numeral to its ASCII-range Unicode equivalent. You need to map the Devanagari character-as-string (or its codepoint value) to a Latin digit 0-9 (especially if you need to do any calculations with these numbers).

Comment: thanks for the information. :) I devised another (and simpler solution): 
`var str = "००७"; /*unicode*/

 var newStr=""; 

 for(i=0; i<len(str); i++) {

 switch(str[i]) {

 case "०": newStr += "0"; break;

 ......

}

 }

 newInt = eval(newStr); `

Comment: that worked for me just because the locale used decimal radix :)